# How do you call a void C function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ffi

I am attempting to call the main function of a C file in Haskell using the foreign function interface.

The main function is declared:

```
int main(void);
```

I am unable to figure out what to tell the Haskell function to do with the void type. I am unable to modify the C source code.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A function that "takes" `void` like that in C takes no arguments (this looks like more of a C question than a Haskell question). The type to import it with would just be `IO Int`.

(Note that it may not be a good idea to call an actual `main` function from Haskell via the FFI. But that's up to you.)

Comment: For class, we were given some C code and told to write a program in Haskell that does what the C code does. I decided this was the smallest piece of code I could write.

I am trying the following:
`foreign import ccall unsafe "hangman.c main" c_main :: IO CInt`

When I try to do this, I get the following error:
`ByteCodeLink: can't find label
During interactive linking, GHCi couldn't find the following symbol:
  main`

Comment: Yeah `main` tends to be treated specially in various circumstances.  Do you have the ability to rename that function?

Comment: I do not. I was able to get it working though, the problem was that I was not telling GHCI to use the hangman.o file.

Comment: You should probably not use `foreign import ccall unsafe`. Import it `safe` unless you know what you're doing.